# Difference between : and :: in SSH

Tags: ssh

What is the difference between these two segments of an SSH command, when specifying a remote source or destination directory?

`pi@192.168.0.5:/mnt/disk1/Adam/Dropbox/`

`pi@192.168.0.5::/mnt/disk1/Adam/Dropbox/`

In which cases should `:` be used over `::`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the double colon syntax is used when connecting to an rsync server without using ssh or rsh as the transport.

Comment: Is the double colon thing just an rsync thing then? Because I was advised to use it with rdiff-backup by the manual page but can't understand why.

Comment: I've only ever seen the double colon with rsync, or in some IPv6 addresses where a group containing only a zero has been compressed, e.g.  fe80:0:0:0:2aa:ff:fe9a:4ca2 could be written like fe80::2aa:ff:fe9a:4ca2

Comment: After some more practice with rsync, rdiff-backup and ssh, it appears the `::` only occurs within rsync and rdiff-backup. Maybe it's a double escape character sort of thing, similar to how the `%%s` works in rsync when using the `--remote-schema` option.

Comment: "The remote-shell transport is used whenever the source or destination path contains a single colon (:) separator after a host specification. Contacting an rsync daemon directly happens when the source or destination path contains a double colon (::) separator..." https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html